# It's there any way to change the position of image according to screen size?

Tags: android

I doing a project where I have to display arrow on a map which is a picture. The base map will will stretch or compressed when different screen is used. However the position of arrow still remain the same. Is that any way to make the arrow follow the map ?

[image]

Image 1 is when i use a smaller screen while image 2 is when i use a larger scrren

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

tools:context="com.example.window8.rescape.Escape"
android:id="@+id/main"

>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:background="@drawable/basebase" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/pointer"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/pointer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="198dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="68px" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80px" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you want those arrows to point to the exits? left and rights only. or do you have other situations? the answer I provided solves a general problem. if what you want is only to point to top left and right corners your solution is much easier. just add the arrows inside a frame layout and set the layout gravity for the arrows top left and top right!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the LinearLayout that contains the arrows add 2 LinearLayouts. one before the 1st arrows and another one between the arrows. Also, add weight sum to the parent LinearLayout as follow:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="68px" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, you need to play with the weight values for the 2 linear layouts until you find the desired ones.

Answer (score 0):

Put your arrows inside a FrameLayout and add a layout_gravity attributes to them:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="68px"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow2"
        android:layout_marginRight="68px"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: I feel your method will be easier , but duno why can't work still trying

Comment: set the with to be 0dp and height to be wrap_content and add a weight to the arrows to achieve that.

Comment: I use your second answer which suits me, just need tons of patient!

Comment: you can do that in photoshop or something to calculate the ratios only once. then do it in code.

Comment: if you have a problem with the emulator being slow. search how you can accelerate it. there is a way to do that.